# sequence to sequence model using pytorch

Tags: deep-learning, model, pytorch, lstm, seq

I have dataset (sequence to sequence), each sample input is seq of charterers (combination from from 20 characters and max length 2166) and out is list of charterers (combination of three characters G,H,B). for example **OIREDSSSRTTT ----> GGGHHHHBHBBB**
I would like to do simple pytorch model that work in that type of dataset. Model that can predict sequence of classes. I would appreciate any suggestions or links for simple mode that do the same?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If the output sequence always has the same length as the input sequence, you might want to use [transformer encoder](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.TransformerEncoderLayer.html), because it basically transforms the inputs with attention to the context. Also you can try to use anything that is used to tagging: BiLSTM, BiGRU, etc.

If you want your model to be able to predict sequences of different length (not necessary the same as input length), look at some encoder-decoder models, such as vanilla transformer.

Answer (score 0):

You can start with the sequence tagging model from PyTorch tutorial https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/nlp/sequence_models_tutorial.html .

As @Ilya Fedorov said, you can move to transformer models for potentially better performance.